# Does Quarkus CDI have a feature that supports dependency resolution in a manner similar to Guice's module bindings?

Tags: quarkus

Does Quarkus support dependency resolution for an interface with multiple implementations via code without relying on `Producer` methods?

For example, suppose there's a third party library that has an interface `Car` with `Van` and `Sedan` implementation classes. Let's say our application only ever wants to use the `Sedan` implementation. We can deal with this in Quarkus via a `Producer` method:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Producers {

    @Produces 
    @Singleton
    Car names() {
      return new Sedan();
    }
}
```

Are there other ways to accomplish the same thing? For example, in Guice, we can use the bind method, which is more concise:

```
public class CarModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
      bind(Car.class).to(Sedan.class).in(Singleton.class);
  }
}
```

The documentation (https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi and https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference) doesn't reveal such a capability, but I wanted to double check.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of a `module` in Quarkus' implementation of CDI